# Live connection shopify database

Tags: shopify

Is there any way to connect to shopify database tables? 
Requirement: 
I need to create a live connection to drag the store data to Excel spread sheets ? So that I can analyze the data. I know there are adds on plugins that help to analyze shopify data but i need to compare with the other data sets like from shipping side.

Comment: You have the [shopify api](https://docs.shopify.com/api]) for developers

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot connect to Shopify database tables. Instead, authenticate yourself using an API key to get access to a shop, with permission to read orders. Then you can download all the orders and analyze the data as you need to. Or, just log in to the shop and use the built-in Export of the data.

Answer (score 0):

No way to connect database table because its multi-store hosted solution so as part of security perceptive it will never available as I feel.

You can create app and integrate it to store to do same things, but for the you should have to take the developer help or you need to aware with some programming language like php, dotnet, ror, etc

Its very clear from shopify that to extend the any part of the shopify feature we need to create a apps.

Shopify Plus already in the market that allowing some more customization but that is bit of costly compare to normal shopify store subscription